How to change the value of promethues internal label
I have an internal label on the target __meta_consul_service_port="8300"
I would like to set the value to 8501 in the relabel_configs
What I tried so far,
- job_name: 'conul'
  consul_sd_configs:
  - server: '127.0.0.1:8500'
    services: ['consul']
  relabel_configs:
  - action: replace
    replacement: 8501
    target_label: __meta_consul_service_port

- job_name: 'conul'
  consul_sd_configs:
  - server: '127.0.0.1:8500'
    services: ['consul']
  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__meta_consul_service_port]
    target_label: __meta_consul_service_port
    replacement: '8051'

Nothing works! any help?

Labels starting with __ will be removed from the label set after target relabeling is completed.. See also Relabeler
